# How to retain all new added NoteCards on window reload

Tags: javascript

I am building a NoteCard Web Application. I am trying to store and get a non-string element('NoteCard element')

When the user reloads the window, it only keeps one('The last added noteCard') of the newly added notecards while the rest disappears. How can I make it keep every newNoteCard that is usually added when the user reloads the window?

**Significant part of the code:**

```
function createNewNoteCard(backgroundColor){
```

**Create a new article**

```
      const article = document.createElement('article');
```

**Add article class**

```
article.classList.add('note-card', 'newCard');
```

**Increment the note index**

```
const noteIndex = (noteCards.length) + 1;
      article.setAttribute('data-note-index', noteIndex);
```

**Create pTag text class**

```
const pTextClass = document.createElement('p');
      pTextClass.contentEditable = 'false'
      pTextClass.className = 'text';
      pTextClass.appendChild(document.createTextNode('It\'s a lovely day.'));
```

**append pTag to article**

```
article.appendChild(pTextClass);
```

**Create editIcon text class**

```
      const edit = document.createElement('div');
      edit.className = 'edit';

      const iElement = document.createElement('i');
      edit.appendChild(iElement);
      iElement.classList.add('large', 'material-icons');
      iElement.textContent = 'edit';

      edit.appendChild(iElement);
```

**append EditIcon to article**

```
article.appendChild(edit);
```

**Create date element**

```
const date = document.createElement('div');
      date.className = 'date';
      date.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));
```

**append date to article**

```
article.appendChild(date);
```

**Apply the background color style**

```
    article.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;

      return article; //Return the newly created article
    }
```

====================================================================================
**// Append newArticle**

```
function addNewNoteCard(colorClass, backgroundColor) {
```

**Increment the note index based on the number of existing note cards**

```
      const noteIndex = noteCards.length + 1;
```

**Call your createNewNoteCard function to create a new article.**

```
const article = createNewNoteCard(backgroundColor, noteIndex);
```

**Append the newly created article to your articles container.**

```
const articlesContainer = document.querySelector('.articles-container');
      articlesContainer.appendChild(article);

      const content = article.querySelector('.text').textContent;
      const date = article.querySelector('.date').textContent;

      localStorage.setItem(`note-content-${noteIndex}`, content);
      localStorage.setItem(`note-date-${noteIndex}`, date);
```

**Store the HTML of the new note card in localStorage**

```
localStorage.setItem(`note-html-${noteIndex}`, article.outerHTML);
```

**Attach the edit icon click event listener to the newly added note card**

```
      const editIcon = article.querySelector('.edit');
      editIcon.addEventListener('click', toggleEditMode);
    }
```

==========================================================================================

```
 "window.onload = function (){
      let maxNoteIndex = 0; **Track the maximum note index**
```

**Load and display note cards from localStorage**

```
const articlesContainer = document.querySelector('.articles-container');
```

**Find the maximum note index in localStorage**

```
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        const key = localStorage.key(i);
        if (key.startsWith('note-html-')) {
          const noteIndex = parseInt(key.replace('note-html-', ''));
          if (noteIndex > maxNoteIndex) {
            maxNoteIndex = noteIndex;
          }
        }
      }
```

**Load note cards based on the maximum note index**

```
      for (let noteIndex = 1; noteIndex <= maxNoteIndex; noteIndex++) {
        const noteHTML = localStorage.getItem(`note-html-${noteIndex}`);
        if (noteHTML) {
          const tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
          tempDiv.innerHTML = noteHTML;
          const newNoteCard = tempDiv.firstElementChild;
          articlesContainer.appendChild(newNoteCard);
        }
      }"
```

I tried passing the localStorage in a JSON.strinify and parse since I am trying to store a non-String but it didn't give me what I expected.

I went to get help from chatGPT but the result provided worked but only keeps one('The last added noteCard') of the newly added notecards while the rest disappeared.

Comment: Make your code short, concise and focused on your problem. Since you lose information on `window.reload`, looks like something's wrong with `localStorage` contents. So at this point, none of your code except for local storage related snippets matters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+store+html+in+localStorage+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read localStorage immediately

   ```
   <head>
     ....
     <script>
       const cards = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cards") || '[]'); // set or initialise
   ```
2. Define your container only once, in a dom ready handler:

   ```
   window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
     const articlesContainer = document.getElementById('articles-container'); // I suggest using an ID instead of class to point oit there is only one
   ```
3. Write only ONCE when the card is updated and do not re-read the content

   ```
   const content = getText(.....)
   const newCard = createArticleObject(content,new Date()); // hold ALL the variables for one card
   cards.push(newCard)
   renderCards(); // append or rewrite or whatever
   localStorage.setItem("cards",JSON.stringify(cards))
   ```